# iOS app binary submission: submitted from Xcode but it does not appear in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, submission

I've validated and submitted my app from Xcode. I received a warning saying "Archive submission completed with warnings", and saying that I must support 64-bits starting February 1. But as faras I understand, this is just a warning, and the warning's header says "Archive submission completed". However, the binary is not appearing in my iTunes Connect entry, has somebody experienced the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

1. iTunes Connect
2. My Apps
3. Your App Name
4. Scroll down to "Build" and select the build you just uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the warning is to remind you that starting in February 1st, 2015, all iOS Apps need to provide 64-bit support. This is not an error nor is it a reason for rejection of your app.

[image]

As for the app on itunes connect, have you checked in: your_app/Prerelease ?

if you see this (in the page of your app) means that you have not uploaded any build

[image]

if you see this (in the page of your app) means you have successfully loaded one or more build

[image]

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html)